# Amount of spaces calculation in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I made a program in C++ that draws out a Christmas Tree however, I'm having some issues with the stump. I literally cannot see why it doesn't want to appear in the middle (in line with the top of the tree, to make the entire tree symmetrical).

I've got nested for loops however, am I calculating the correct spaces?

Here's what I have so far in terms of code:

```
int treeHeight;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the size of the tree (4-20): ";
    cin >> treeHeight;

    void getValidHeight();
    getValidHeight();

    // Set tree height to 2 lower than it is (part of spec I'm following)
    treeHeight = treeHeight - 2;

    // Set tree character 
    char leaf = '#';

    // Set tree stump character 
    char treeStump = '|';

    // First leaf (top of tree)
    int leaves = 1;

    int treeWidth = treeHeight / 2;

    int stumpHeight = 2;

    for (int total = treeHeight; total > 0; --total)
    {
        //control the amount of spaces
        for (int i = (total - 1); i > 0; --i)
            cout << " ";

        //control the amount of leaves
        for (int j = 0; j < leaves; ++j)
        {
                cout << leaf;
        }

        // Next row needs 2 extra leaves
        leaves += 2;

        cout << '\n';
    }

    // Create the stump
    for (int i = 0; i < stumpHeight; ++i)
    {
        // Spaces to the center of the tree so that the stump is centered
        for (int j = 0; j < treeWidth; ++j)
            cout << " ";

        for (int k = 0; k < 1; ++k)
            cout << treeStump;

        cout << '\n';
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void getValidHeight()
{
    while (treeHeight > 20 || treeHeight < 4)
    {
        cout << "\nEROOR: Invalid height! Enter the size of the tree (4-20): ";
        cin >> treeHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: treeWidth isn't used at all when drawing the tree so is unlikely to be correct for the stump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your tree width is not half of the tree height! For example, try changing the width to

```
int treeWidth = treeHeight*2;
```

and then write the spaces before the trunk like so:

```
// Spaces to the center of the tree so that the stump is centered
for (int j = 0; j < treeWidth/2-1; ++j)
    cout << " ";
```

I also added a new line at the very top, before the tree. Merry Christmas!

```
                 #
                ###
               #####
              #######
             #########
            ###########
           #############
          ###############
         #################
        ###################
       #####################
      #######################
     #########################
    ###########################
   #############################
  ###############################
 #################################
###################################
                 |
                 |
```

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I missed that... Thanks for pointing that out! Merry Christmas to you too!

Comment: Note that the width is not fully two times the height due to the two last lines being only the trunk.